# Python - selenium - how to click on the button

Tags: python, selenium

I'm try to code with python , using selenium to do search and click the button.
my code as below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time 
path = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
driver.get("https://hopamviet.vn")
#import them
# from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
# from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
# from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
########

# driver.get('http://codepad.org')
# #click radio button - select python
# python_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='lang' and @value='Python']")
# python_button.click()
# #send text "print('hello world')"
# text_area = driver.find_element_by_id('textarea')
# text_area.send_keys("print('Hello World')")
# #click submit button
# submit_button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="editor-form"]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/div/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/button')[0]
# submit_button.click()
search = driver.find_element_by_name("song")
search.send_keys("Hello")
search.send_keys(keys.RETURN)

#click search
submit_button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/nav/div/form/div/span/button')
submit_button.click()
```

for search button , I'm using "find_elements_by_xpath" method to select xpath then click(). but it didn't give me the result as i expected. Can you please help look ? below is HTML code:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above line of code

```
#click search
submit_button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/nav/div/form/div/span/button')
submit_button.click()
```

is not certainly true, cause you are using `find_elements` which will return a list in python.

Instead use `find_element`

```
#click search
submit_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/nav/div/form/div/span/button')
submit_button.click()
```

Also, the xpath is absolute, try to use relative xpath like this

```
//i[contains(@class,'search')]//parent::button
```

**full code with explicit waits :**

```
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
driver.get("https://hopamviet.vn")
search = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, "song")))
search.send_keys("Hello")

#click search
submit_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//i[contains(@class,'search')]//parent::button")))
submit_button.click()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: thank you so much , the code work fine. Btw , sorry for my question , i don't realy understand this line "//i[contains(@class,'search')]//parent::button" , can you give me some docs related this ? it is not the same with xpath gotten from chrome inspector , right ?

Comment: Yes it's a customized xpath not the one we get from chrome inspector. Please read more about it here https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp